# Gii page not showing in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I am new to yii but I have covered the installation section of the guide. I could use gii on windows but I could not even access the page on Ubuntu 12.04. I installed both the basic and advanced frameworks and used the url 
"localhost/advanced/frontend/web/index.php?=gii" and 
"localhost/advanced/backend/web/index.php?=gii" for advanced and 
"localhost/basic/web/index.php?=gii" for basic but it did not direct me to the Gii page. Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try "localhost/advanced/frontend/web/index.php?r=gii"

I assume you have made the right config in main.php